# Use jQuery to sort Select field

Tags: jquery, forms, sorting, select, input

I've got a select field and I need to sort the options into groups, but not by ascending or descending value.

I've got gaming platforms and gaming genres and I want to separate them out into two groups within the same drop-down select field.

Right now all of the elements are alphabetical order in the select field like this:

```
3DS
Action
Android
Beat 'Em Up
First Person Shooter
iOS
```

And I want to sort them with genres first then platforms like this:

```
Action
Beat 'Em Up
First Person Shooter
3DS
Android
iOS
```

Each option has a numerical value I can use to identify it, but how do I change it's position/order within the select field?

```
$("select#cat option[value='45']");
```

Thanks!  :D

Comment: where are you pulling these values from? is it a SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/UqNrN/
HTML

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="4">3DS</option>
<option value="1">Action</option>
<option value="5">Android</option>
<option value="2">Beat 'Em Up</option>
<option value="3">First Person Shooter</option>
<option value="6">iOS</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').find('option').detach().sort(function(a, b){
        return a.value - b.value;
    }).appendTo('#test').parent().val('1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the select with the options ordered this way:

```
$(function(){
    var valueOrder = [46, 33, 21, 54, ...]//Specify the values order here
        opts = "";

    $.each(valueOrder, function (index, value) {
        opts += $("select#cat option[value='" + value + "']").get(0).outerHTML;//Get the option html
    });

    $("select#cat").html(opts);//build select with ordered options html
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using multiple select boxes.

```
var games = [
    {
        "name": "iOS and Android Game",
        "categories": ["ios", "android"]
    },
    {
        "name":"a 3ds game",
        "categories": ["3ds"]
    },
    {
        "name":"an action game",
        "categories": ["action"]
    }
]

$("#categories").on("change", function(){
    var that = $(this);
    $("#games").empty();
    $.each(games, function(index, value){
        if (value["categories"].indexOf(that.val()) === -1) return;
        $("#games").append("<option>" + value["name"] + "</option>");
    })
})
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/B3X7z/1/)